# Django-Edit and update the existing data in database

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py is

```
from django.db import models

    class Book(models.Model):

        book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
        book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
        author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
        publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

        class Meta:
            db_table = u'Book'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return "%d %s %s %s" % (self.book_id,self.book_name, self.author_name,self.publisher_name)
```

forms.py is

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Book


class BookForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

        fields=['book_id','book_name','author_name','publisher_name']
```

my views.py is

```
def editbook(request,book_id):

    queryset = Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id)
    if request.POST:
        form=BookForm(request.POST,instance=queryset)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form=BookForm(instance=queryset)
        template = 'editbook.html'
        book = { 'form':form }
    return render_to_response(template, book , RequestContext(request))
```

I need to edit and update the already existing row of data in the database.I guess that their is some problem in views.py. So I am not sure my views.py is right. Please check and tell me if any problem and how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

views.py

```
 if request.POST:
        book_form = BookForm(request.POST)

    if book_form.is_valid():

        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        book_form = BookForm(request.POST, instance = book)
        book_form.save() #cleaned indenting, but would not save unless I added at least 6 characters.
        return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        book = Book.objects.get(pk = book_id)       
        book_form = BookForm(instance=book)

        return render_to_response('editbook.html',{ 'form':book_form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Please AT LEAST post syntactically valid code :facepalm: